# How to handle FirebaseInstanceId.getToken() returning null

Tags: android, firebase

A recent update of the Firebase Messaging Android SDK (`com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0`) added an `@Nullable` return type annotation to the `FirebaseIntanceId.getToken(String senderId, String scope)` method.

Since we are using Kotlin in our own code using this SDK, we now get a compilation error as the inferred return type is no longer `String` but `String?`.

The question is: what do we need to do when the `getToken()` call returns `null`?

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#public-string-gettoken-string-senderid,-string-scope) does not mention the case where `null` is returned or what the client code needs to do in this case.

What are the best practises for this case? Re-request `getToken()` right away, re-request it with some sort of exponential back-off?

Comment: why would the token even be a nullable type if it can't be null..?

Comment: @a_local_nobody what makes you say that it can't be null?

Comment: i'm not, i was wondering why they would make it nullable but provide no documentation for cases where it COULD be null

Answer (score 0):

Google added in a callback approach where you add in an [OnCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnCompleteListener) to the call and it is retrieved asynchronously.

Here is some sample java code:

```
private static String fcmId;

/**
 * Get the FCMID using a callback method
 */
public static void getFCMID(){
    try {
        FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(
                task -> {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            task.getException().printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e){}
                        fcmId = null;
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID");
                        return;
                    }
                    InstanceIdResult result = task.getResult();
                    if(result == null){
                        fcmId = null;
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID");
                        return;
                    }
                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    String token = result.getToken();
                    if(!token.isEmpty()){
                        fcmId = token;
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Success! Do stuff with FCMID");
                    } else {
                        fcmId = null;
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID");
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e){
        fcmId = null;
        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here it is in Kotlin:

```
private var fcmId: String? = null

/**
 * Get the FCMID using a callback method
 */
fun getFCMID() {
    try {
        FirebaseApp.getInstance()
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val result = task.result
                if (result != null) {
                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    val token = result!!.token
                    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
                        fcmId = token
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Success! Do stuff with FCMID")
                    } else {
                        fcmId = null
                        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID")
                    }
                } else {
                    fcmId = null
                    Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID")
                }
            } else {
                fcmId = null
                Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID")
            }            
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        fcmId = null
        Log.d("FMCID", "Could not retrieve FCMID")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

My usual approach is it run it, get the token assigned, and then save it to the shared preferences or save it within a singleton, ie in your class that extends `Application`.

Comment: with the code you've posted, wouldn't it just crash if `val token = result!!.token` result token is null ?

Comment: Good question! But no need to worry, the `InstanceIdResult` interface is specifically marked with the `@NonNull` annotation:  `@NonNull
    String getToken();`

Comment: @Silmarilos Thanks for the code. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `getInstanceId()` is not the same as calling `getToken(senderId, scope)`. The former returns the Firebase Project id while the latter authorises the given `senderId` for the given project. So unfortunately I don't think this solves our issue since `getToken(senderId, scope)` does not use the `InstanceIdResult` with `@NonNull` return type

Comment: The code I posted above returns the firebase token that can be used to send messages. In your question, you noted you were using the `Firebase Messaging Android SDK` and this is the token used to ping those users using the `to` field in [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). Are you trying to use this token for a different purpose or different SDK?

Comment: @Silmarilos Ah OK, sorry in my question I should have specified this is in our Android app in order to receive notifications, not on the server sending them. We are using this `getToken(senderId, scope)` when registering the app with Firebase.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then yes, you are correct in that this will not help you. I will leave the code up in case anyone needs a reference on obtaining the FCMID for sending push notifications though.